# Поиск параметров в строке: использовать '' если не найден

Tags: python, search

Всем привет, уважаемые знатоки.

Есть следующий код:

```
params = ['Test 11', 'Test 22', 'Test 33', 'ATest 44', 'BsTEST 55']
d = {'Test 11': 'Success', 'Test 22_434': 'Success', 'Test 33': 'Fail'}
res = []
for param in params:
    for index in d.keys():
        if param in index:
            res.append(d[index])

print(res)  ['Success', 'Success', 'Fail']
```

Идет сравнение списка параметров с тем, что лежит в словаре. Если есть параметр типа: `Test 22` и ключ в словаре: `Test 22_434`, то в `res` должно записаться значения ключа `Test 22_434` т.е. `'Success'`.

Нужно добавить небольшое условие, что если совпадения из параметров со словарем нет, то записать `res.append('')`.
Чтобы было вот так:

```
print(res)  ['Success', 'Success', 'Fail', '' , '']
```

Не удается сообразить, как лучше это обыграть.

Comment: а если попадется такой случай `d = {'Test 11': 'Success', 'Test 111': 'Success'}` ?

Comment: Такой вариант не возможен. список параметров жестко задан и различия могут быть только в добавлении к параметру какого-то значения, например : параметр_значение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
params = ['Test 11', 'Test 22', 'Test 33', 'ATest 44', 'BsTEST 55']
d = {'Test 11': 'Success', 'Test 22_434': 'Success', 'Test 33': 'Fail'}

res = []


def find_param(param):
    for key in d:
        if key.startswith(param):
            return d[key]
    return ''


for param in params:
    res.append(find_param(param))


print(res)
```

Comment: чё за магия? откуда появилась эта запятая? )))

Comment: Не работает. Перечитайте условие еще раз, пожалуйста. Я внес туда корректировку, о которой сразу не уточнил.

Comment: @Andy R исправил соответственно вашей поправке

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч спасибо, то, что нужно!

Answer (score 2):

Так как каждому параметру не более одного ключа соответствует, то можно [`next(values, default)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) форму использовать для поиска:

```
result = [next((value for key, value in d.items() if key.startswith(param)), '')
          for param in params]
```